# Materialize Collapsible Content Outside Collapsible Body

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am new to using Materialize and I am having an issue with this section of code.

```
<ul class="collapsible">
      <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header orange darken-4 white-text"><i class="material-icons">add</i>Add Client</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body white"><span>
          <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input id="customer" placeholder='Customer'type="text">
              <label class='orange darken-4 white-text' for="customer">Customer</label>
          </div> 
          <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input id="address1" placeholder='Address 1'type="text">
              <label class='orange darken-4 white-text' for="address1">Address 1</label>
          </div> 
          <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input id="address2" placeholder='Address 2'type="text">
              <label class='orange darken-4 white-text' for="address2">Address 2</label>
          </div> 
          <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input id="city" placeholder='City'type="text">
              <label class='orange darken-4 white-text' for="city">City</label>
          </div> 
          <div class="input-field col s4">
              <input id="postcode" placeholder='Postcode'type="text">
              <label class='orange darken-4 white-text' for="postcode">Postcode</label>
          </div> 
          <div class='col s4'>
          <a class="waves-effect  orange darken-4 btn-small" id='add-client'><i class="material-icons left">add</i>Add</a>
          </div>
        </span></div>
     </li>
    </ul>
```

When you open the collapsible the content area is correct momentarily then retreats with the input elements displayed outside the collapsible body.

I am using a similar thing in a different area displaying tables, which works perfectly, therefore I am assuming it is something to do with the `<div>`elements within the body section.

If someone could point me in the direction of what I am missing it would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code sample is fine, works perfectly in my codepen. I suspect you've got a conflict from somewhere else https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/NWxvxmR

Comment: I appreciate you looking into it. I'll see what I can find!. Many thanks